Vue filter modify results to restrict elements returned instead of adding them
I have an example of elements to be filtered, if the filter is quite selected the items should be very few or none, because condition are hardly meet. in the source code here the filter is adding elements instead restricting them from appearing in the result set, how can I change the condition or expresion to restrict elements instead of adding

 get filteredProducts() {
      // products that have either a skill or usage value present within active filters
      if (!this.activeFilters.length) return this.products
      return this.products.filter(prod => (
        [prod.skill, prod.usage].some(val => this.activeFilters.includes(val))
      ))
    },
    activeFilters,
    products
  },

full example from here
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->


<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en' class=''>
<head><script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/console_runner-079c09a0e3b9ff743e39ee2d5637b9216b3545af0de366d4b9aad9dc87e26bfd.js'></script><script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/events_runner-73716630c22bbc8cff4bd0f07b135f00a0bdc5d14629260c3ec49e5606f98fdd.js'></script><script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/css_live_reload_init-2c0dc5167d60a5af3ee189d570b1835129687ea2a61bee3513dee3a50c115a77.js'></script><meta charset='UTF-8'><meta name="robots" content="noindex"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-8ea04875e70c4b0bb41da869e81236e54394d63638a1ef12fa558a4a835f1164.ico" /><link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-f2d2b6d2c61838f7e76325261b7195c27224080bc099486ddd6dccb469b8e8e6.svg" color="#111" /><link rel="canonical" href="https://codepen.io/erikjung/pen/qmpjYm?depth=everything&order=popularity&page=83&q=vue&show_forks=false" />

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<style class="cp-pen-styles">html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

view-container {
  background: #eee;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(20ch, 20vw) minmax(40ch, auto);
  grid-template-areas:
    "hd hd"
    "sd bd"
    "ft ft";
}

view-container > * {
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

view-head {
  grid-area: hd;
}

view-controls {
  grid-area: sd;
}

view-content {
  grid-area: bd;
}

view-foot {
  grid-area: ft;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

product-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10ch, 20ch));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}</style></head><body>
<view-container id="app">
  <view-head>
    <h3>Products</h3>
  </view-head>
  
  <view-controls>
    <div v-for="(filterset, key) in filters" style="min-width:20ch">
      <h6 v-text="`Filter by ${key}`"></h6>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="form-check" v-for="filter in filterset">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" 
                   type="checkbox" 
                   name="filters" 
                   v-bind:value="filter"
                   v-model="activeFilters">
            <span v-text="filter"></span>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <p v-if="activeFilters.length">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" 
              type="button"
              v-on:click="clearFilters">Clear Filters</button>
    </p>
  </view-controls>
  
  <view-content>
    <h6 v-text="`${filteredProducts.length} results`"></h6>
    <p v-if="activeFilters.length">
      <small class="text-muted" v-text="`Filtered by ${activeFilters.join(', ')}`"></small>
    </p>
    <product-grid>
      <div class="card" v-for="product in filteredProducts">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="http://fpoimg.com/300x200" alt="">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h5 class="card-title" v-text="product.name"></h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            <span v-text="`Price: $${product.price.toFixed(2)}`"></span>
            <br>
            <span v-text="`Skill: ${product.skill}`"></span>
            <br>
            <span v-text="`Usage: ${product.usage}`"></span>
          </p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Buy</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </product-grid>
  </view-content>
  
  <view-foot>
    <p>
      <small class="text-muted" v-text="`${products.length} total / ${filteredProducts.length} shown`"></small>
    </p>
  </view-foot>
</view-container>
<script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-b2a7b3fe212eaa732349046d8416e00a9dec26eb7fd347590fbced3ab38af52e.js'></script><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js'></script><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.23.0/ramda.min.js'></script>
<script >const products = [
  {name: 'Product 1', usage: 'Home', skill: 'Easy', price: 100.00},
  {name: 'Product 2', usage: 'Home', skill: 'Intermediate', price: 120.00},
  {name: 'Product 3', usage: 'Office', skill: 'Intermediate', price: 190.00},
  {name: 'Product 4', usage: 'Office', skill: 'Advanced', price: 260.00},
  {name: 'Product 5', usage: 'Warehouse', skill: 'Advanced', price: 320.00},
  {name: 'Product 6', usage: 'Farm', skill: 'Intermediate', price: 120.00},
  {name: 'Product 7', usage: 'Space', skill: 'Advanced', price: 157920.00},
  {name: 'Product 8', usage: 'Bathroom', skill: 'Easy', price: 9.00}
]

const tru = val => Boolean(val) === true

const hashValues = () => (
  location.hash.replace(/^#/, '').split(',').filter(tru)
)

const activeFilters = hashValues()

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    get uses() { 
      return R.pipe(R.pluck('usage'), R.uniq)(products)
    },
    get skills() { 
      return R.pipe(R.pluck('skill'), R.uniq)(products)
    },
    get filters() {
      return {
        'Usage': this.uses,
        'Skill': this.skills
      }
    },
    get filteredProducts() {
      // products that have either a skill or usage value present within active filters
      if (!this.activeFilters.length) return this.products
      return this.products.filter(prod => (
        [prod.skill, prod.usage].some(val => this.activeFilters.includes(val))
      ))
    },
    activeFilters,
    products
  },
  methods: {
    clearFilters() {
      this.activeFilters.splice(0, this.activeFilters.length)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    activeFilters: newVal => {
      location.hash = newVal.join(',')
    }
  }
})

window.onhashchange = () => {
  activeFilters.splice(0, activeFilters.length, ...hashValues())
}
//# sourceURL=pen.js
</script>
</body></html>

im expecting to return fewer elements out of the filter, when adding conditions, AND instead of an OR

[prod.skill, prod.usage].some(val => this.activeFilters.includes(val))

This line of code can be understood to be returning true when either product skill or product usage equals any value found in the array of active filters.
You want instead to return true if every active filter is found to be included in either the product skill or product usage.
get filteredProducts() {
  // products that have skill and/or usage values matching all active filters
  if (!this.activeFilters.length) return this.products
  return this.products.filter(prod => (
    this.activeFilters.every(filter => [prod.skill, prod.usage].includes(filter))
  ))
},

